# How to prevent hyphenation in title (\maketitle)?

Tags: hyphenation, titles

I want to have a `\maketitle` title page where every word in the title is not hyphenated. Elsewhere I wouldn't mind hyphenation of the title (e.g., in the Reference List), but on the title page it looks very bad!

I'm using the report class.

It seemed like an obvious question, but I haven't found answers on Stackexchange nor elsewhere no the web.

Comment: `\maketitle` is defined by the document class, so we need to know the class you are using.

Comment: @lockstep I've updated my question to reflect your request; I didn't realise it was related to the class, but apologies for not doing so in the first instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be curious to see an actual example of a title with hyphenation, since my attempts to construct one failed.  But if such a problem exists, you can selectively turn of hyphenation using the `hyphenat` package.

```
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\title{\nohyphens{Your title}}
...
\maketitle
```

Comment: `\title{\hyphenpenalty=10000 Brief Article of the hypersupersuperdupercalifragilisticexpihalidocioushypersupersuperdupercalifragilisticexpihalidocious}` without the penalty setting will hyphenate:)

Comment: @Yiannis That even causes an overfull \hbox on the web page! :-) But seriously, with normal, even quite long words it's not that easy to get a title in any documentclass to hyphenate.

Comment: For whatever reason, in my report two words in the title were hyphenated, one of which was `au-ral'. In any case, your answers rectifies the situation (and so does using \hyphenpenalty as suggested by @Yiannis); I thank you both. I would prefer not having macros in the \title command but instead changing the \maketitle command to not hyphenate, in case the \title command affects other things like the PDF title etc. (which I think it doesn't, so it's not a problem for now).

Comment: @stahmo Changing the `maketitle` command is quite a bit more complicated.  If you do want to go that route, the `titling` package is helpful in that regard.

Comment: It seems that `\nohyphens` is not imperative - i.e. depending on the paragraph I still get a hyphenation.