# List Parsing the ascii space character

Tags: spacing, symbols, etoolbox, parsing

I have been using the list parsing functionality from etoolbox and I have a weird use case in which I want a space separated list.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\DeclareListParser*{\symbolListParser}{<symbol for space character>}
\newcommand{\processSymbolList}[1]{
    \symbolListParser{}{#1}
}
```

I am unsure where to even start looking. I have poked around for a while looking at documentation about lists, documentation about space, and documentation about ascii characters to no avail.

so if someone could either tell me how to do it, where to look or that it isn't possible I would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE:** I did find [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11595/iterate-over-space-separated-list) but I was looking for something a bit cleaner like what the OP wanted

**UPDATE2:** Thanks to Tobi for the answer. I've accepted it. below is a more general version of spacelist that behaves more like the list parser

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{ \spacelist }{ mm }{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #2 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
        #1{##1}
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% to use you would write it like:
\spacelist{\fbox}{Boxes and Spaces in a List}
```

Comment: I don't think `etoolbox` lists can be space separated. It probably depends on the implementation, where probably both delimited and undelimited arguments are used; when TeX is looking for an undelimited argument, it ignores spaces as it goes, and this may explain the infinite loop it enters if you use `{ }` as the delimiter argument.

Comment: @egreg that is correct. that is what Tobi pointed out. so I posted code that does not use etoolbox and instead uses xparse and expl3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an approach using `expl3`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{ \spacelist }{ m }{
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
   \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
      \fbox { ##1 }
   }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
List: \spacelist{Boxes and Spaces in a List}
\end{document}
```

The code uses so called *sequences* which is generated by splitting the Argument `#1`of `\spacelist` at spaces, which are `~` in the new syntax*, while normal spaces are ignored. The sequins ist stored in a local, temporarily variable named `\l_tempa_seq` and with `\seq_map_inline` we can iterate through all items of the sequence. The current item is given as argument code `#1`, here it is `##1` because the mapping is nested inside a definition.

You may replace the `\fbox` part to fit your needs …

---

* *new syntax* means the syntax introduced with LaTeX3 which is currently available as the `expl3`packed, which is loaded by `xparse`. To find out more look at the manual of `expl3` or `source3`.

Answer (score 1):

The `listofitems` package can provide it, in either rendered or detokenized form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\spacelist[2][]{
  \setsepchar{ }%
  \readlist\mylist{#2}%
  \showitems#1\mylist%
}
\begin{document}
List: \spacelist{Boxes and \textbf{Spaces} in a List}

Tokens: \spacelist[*]{Boxes and \textbf{Spaces} in a List}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write in two lines of TeX macros a no-package approach for your goal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`z 3
\makeatletter
\newcommand\spacelist[1]{\spacelist@boxit #1 {z} }%
\long\def\spacelist@boxit #1 {\ifx z#1\relax\else
         \fbox{#1}\expandafter\spacelist@boxit\fi}
\catcode`z 11
\makeatother

\begin{document}
List: \spacelist{Boxes and Spaces in a List}
\end{document}
```

Admission of guilt: the method is fragile if the parsed list contains `\else` or `\fi` tokens.

[image]

Here is more robust way still with simple means. But argument should not contain catcode 3 letter Z...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\catcode`Z 3
\makeatletter
\newcommand\spacelist[1]{\spacelist@getone{}#1 Z }%
\long\def\spacelist@getone #1 {\spacelist@check #1.Z\spacelist@check{#1}}%
\long\def\spacelist@check  #1Z#2\spacelist@check#3%
        {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
         \expandafter\@gobbletwo % abort parse
         \else
%
% #3 contains the searched for item, but with an empty brace pair
% added, which serves to prevent brace removal in processing
% so I am showing here how to remove it with \expandafter/\@gobble
% initial braces are not lost.
% 
         \fbox{\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobble#3}}%
         \fi
         \spacelist@getone{}}%
\catcode`Z 11
\makeatother

\begin{document}
List: \spacelist{Boxes {and Spaces} in a {List with \if, \else, \end tokens}}

\end{document}
```

[image]